# Как получить массив полный массив инфоблока отзывов?

Tags: php, массивы, ооп, битрикс

У меня есть фильтр, который получает отзывы и запрос который получает запрос:

```
<? require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php';

$arSelect = Array("ID", "NAME", "DETAIL_TEXT","DATE_ACTIVE_FROM");
$arFilter =  Array('IBLOCK_ID' => IBLOCK_REVIEWS_ID, 'ACTIVE' => 'Y');
CModule::IncludeModule('iblock');
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array("SORT"=>"ASC"), $arFilter, false, Array(), $arSelect);
echo '<pre>';
    while($ob = $res->GetNextElement())
    {
      $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
      $arProps  = $ob->GetProperties();

      print_r($arFields);
      print_r($arProps);
    }

echo '</pre>';
```

И я получаю массив не известной наружности с 10 элементами, в котором нет последних отзывов.
https://gist.github.com/vasilukwolf/96a2ba58e95d78c5ead69b1795d772d0

Как вывести полный массив, который попадает в инфоблок?

Comment: что значит "не известной наружности"? в переменной-массиве $arSelect вы указали все данные, что хотите получить

Comment: Я ни где ни писал limit 10. В базе записей 1000. По сему неизвестной наружности. В документах сказано, что по  умолчанию стоит только сортировка. И даже если я убираю фильтрацию, все равно выводит 9 записей. Да, даже print_r

Comment: Кроме того он прикреплен к вопросу.

Comment: 4й параметр в CIBlockGetList - NavParams: Необязательное. По умолчанию false - не ограничивать выводимые элементы.
Если передать в параметр arNavStartParams пустой массив, то ставится ограничение на 10 выводимых элементов. передайте вместо array, false и будет все хорошо ^_^

Comment: А можно в ответ пожалуйста =) и насыпать кармы

Comment: не вопрос! ^_^ спс

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array("SORT"=>"ASC"), $arFilter, false, Array(), $arSelect);
```

4й параметр метода - http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/iblock/classes/ciblockelement/getlist.php - mixed arNavStartParams влияет на кол-во данных:

```
Необязательное. По умолчанию false - не ограничивать выводимые элементы.
Если передать в параметр arNavStartParams пустой массив, то ставится ограничение на 10 выводимых элементов.
```